# Disable previous Dates in ajaxToolkit CalendarExtender

Tags: calendarextender

How to disable previous dates while using in ajaxToolkit CalendarExtender

Answer (score 4):

One Option is to use a rangevalidator on the textbox the calenderextender is bound to. Ie if you have the TargetID of the calendar extender set to tb1 add a rangeValidator to flag when the contents of tb1 is before today.

Another option is using javascript and here is a good example:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=149 TIP 6.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my full solution to the calendar date restriction problem: What I like about this solution is that you set the MinimumValue and MaximumValue of a RangeValidator and you do not have to modify any javascript. I never found a full solution that did not require recompiling the AjaxControlToolkit.dll. Thanks to http://www.karpach.com/ajaxtoolkit-calendar-extender-tweaks.htm for giving me the idea of how to override key methods in the calendar.js file without having to recompile the AjaxControlToolkit.dll. Also, I got "AjaxControlToolkit is undefined" javascript errors, so I changed those to Sys.Extended.UI. and it works for me when using the 4.0 version of the toolkit.

```
<%--//ADD THIS NEW STYLE TO STYLESHEET TO GRAY OUT DATES THAT AREN'T SELECTABLE--%>
<style type="text/css"> 
    .ajax__calendar_inactive  {color:#dddddd;}
</style>
```

Either in Page_Load or Init or wherever, set the min and max values for your range validator:

```
<script runat="server">
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        //set the validator min and max values
        this.valDateMustBeWithinMinMaxRange.MinimumValue = DateTime.Today.Date.ToShortDateString();
        this.valDateMustBeWithinMinMaxRange.MaximumValue = DateTime.MaxValue.Date.ToShortDateString();
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
</script>
```

Add this javascript somewhere in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<%--//   ADD DATE RANGE FEATURE JAVASCRIPT TO OVERRIDE CALENDAR.JS--%>
        var minDate = new Date('<%= valDateMustBeWithinMinMaxRange.MinimumValue %>');
         var maxDate = new Date('<%= valDateMustBeWithinMinMaxRange.MaximumValue %>');
        Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior.prototype._button_onblur_original = Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior.prototype._button_onblur;
        //override the blur event so calendar doesn't close
        Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior.prototype._button_onblur = function (e) {
            if (!this._selectedDateChanging) {
                this._button_onblur_original(e);
            }
        }
        Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior.prototype._cell_onclick_original = Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior.prototype._cell_onclick;
        //override the click event
        Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior.prototype._cell_onclick = function (e) {
            var selectedDate = e.target.date;

            if (selectedDate < minDate || selectedDate > maxDate ) {
                //alert('Do nothing. You can\'t choose that date.');
                this._selectedDateChanging = false;
                return;
            }

            this._cell_onclick_original(e);
        }

        Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior.prototype._getCssClass_original = Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior.prototype._getCssClass;
        Sys.Extended.UI.CalendarBehavior.prototype._getCssClass = function (date, part) {

            var selectedDate = date;

           if (selectedDate < minDate || selectedDate > maxDate ) {
                return "ajax__calendar_inactive";
            }
            this._getCssClass_original(date, part);
        }

</script>
```

Add this text box to your asp.net page with CalendarExtenter and RangeValidator:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBoxDate" runat="server" />
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calendarExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="textBoxDate" />
<asp:RangeValidator ID="valDateMustBeWithinMinMaxRange" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBoxDate"
    ErrorMessage="The date you chose is not in accepted range" Type="Date" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Good implementation.

Comment: Big.  Very big.  Just to disable past dates. Hmm

Answer (score 2):

Using the Ajax toolkit Calendar Extender in the html markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" CssClass="contentfield" Height="16px" MaxLength="12" width="80px" Wrap="False"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server" Enabled="true" StartDate="<%# DateTime.Now %>" EndDate="<%# DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) %>" Format="dd MMM yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgDatePicker" TargetControlID="txtDate">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgDatePicker" runat="Server" AlternateText="Click to show calendar" Height="16px" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" Width="16px" />
```

Above you will see that the Calendar only allows one to choose between today or tomorrow by setting

> StartDate="<%# DateTime.Now %>"

and

> EndDate="<%# DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) %>"

This can also be done in the backend using `CalendarExtender1.StartDate = DateTime.Now;` or `CalendarExtender1.EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);`

Answer (score 1):

Just add an attribute ***StartDate="<%# DateTime.Now %>"*** in you ajaxtoolkit calendarextender control

Comment: This helps set the start date - neater than putting code to set this in page_load :) - but does not block dates in the past, at least not for me :(

Comment: Correction, it does block out of range dates being selected now (I'm actually setting EndDate rather than StartDate) but it doesn't show them stricken out, as it does on other pages - a CSS  styling issue I suspect. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Following link might help you:
[Disable dates in CalendarExtender](http://gratisaccount.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/disable-dates-in-calendarextender/)