# C# code for selecting only from todays date from a calendar

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, datepicker

Hi iam using a calendar control in my application,i need to select only the date from todays date and future date. am using this calendar control in the content place holder,can any one help me out with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to disable all dates in the past? http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/05/03/how-to-disable-previous-dates-in-calendar-control.aspx

Comment: yes,but am using ajax calendar control, there is no such event in ajax control so what could i do now?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820192/disable-previous-dates-in-ajaxtoolkit-calendarextender

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
    }
}
```