# How can I make CalendarExtender StartDate attribute take the current date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I thought something like this

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="txtDatumPoaganje" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" StartDate=<%=DateTime.Now%>>
```

But it doesnt work.  I can make something similar with JavaScript and alert message:

[how to disable previous dates in CalendarExtender control through its render event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608062/how-to-disable-previous-dates-in-calendarextender-control-through-its-render-eve)

but it's not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try SelectedDate instead of StartDate.

Also, the link below says you can't set selecteddate from the html side, instead you must do it from code-behind.

I haven't confirm this however.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1293771.aspx/1

Comment: Sorry it seems like my question was stupid :)
i can make the changes in the *.cs file 
if(!IsPostBack)
extBox1_CalendarExtender.StartDate = DateTime.Now;

Comment: @Filip Not stupid at all. Sometimes you're in the code so far it's hard to step back at times.

Answer (score 2):

you can put this in the load page

`TextBox2_CalendarExtender.StartDate = DateTime.Now.Date;`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to only show dates from `DateTime.Now` onwards, this may help you: [Disable previous Dates in ajaxToolkit CalendarExtender](https://stackoverflow.com/q/820192/441574)