# How to set Startdate is Today in cc2:CalendarExtender?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
                                                             TagPrefix="cc2" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtngaydat" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc2:CalendarExtender ID="CalNgayDat" TargetControlID="txtngaydat" 
                       PopupButtonID="ibtCal" runat="server"></cc2:CalendarExtender>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make CalendarExtender StartDate attribute take the current date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863914/how-can-i-make-calendarextender-startdate-attribute-take-the-current-date)

Comment: I do not understand your idea :o ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set StartDate on Page_Load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CalNgayDat.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: I make but error: Error 14 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' does not contain a definition for 'StartDate' and no extension method 'StartDate' accepting a first argument of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) D:\Study\DoAnIT\BusOnlineTicketsWeb\Default.aspx.cs 22 24 BusOnlineTicketsWeb

Comment: Do you have AjaxControlToolkit in BIN folder or give reference in your project?

Comment: I think you can do with ajax:CalendarExtender :D