# How to set the Min Value to 15 days after current date of RangeValidator?

Tags: c#, validation, date, rangevalidator, calendar-control

I have an ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender who keeps the selected date on a textbox. I want to validate that the selected date is 15 days after current date.

I set the min value, but I get the error when the page id loading:

> The MaximumValue  cannot be less than the MinimumValue 4 Jun 2019 of
>   RangeValidator1.

The max value doesn't matter.

```
RangeValidator1.MinimumValue = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(15).ToShortDateString();
```

To load the page and the textbox to allow dates after the current date with 15 days.

Comment: just add a maximumvalue

Comment: I added and the error is :The MaximumValue 29 Jun 2019 cannot be less than the MinimumValue 4 Jun 2019 of RangeValidator1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the maximum value:

```
RangeValidator1.MaximumValue = System.DateTime.MaxValue.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820192/disable-previous-dates-in-ajaxtoolkit-calendarextender) look at the first answer

Comment: On Page_Load event.